# xpath for text at the end of a HTML-tag

Tags: html, xpath, tags

What is the xpath for the following situation

I try to get the part where it sais:

```
"Here is my text that I would like to get out of this. Bla Bla..."
```

As you can see further down in the HTML-code, this text is at the very end of the -tag

I tried:

```
xpath = "/article()[last()]"
```

But this did not work !

I tried:

```
xpath = "//*[contains(@itemtype, 'http://schema.org/Article')]"
```

But this didn't work either...

I guess, the problem is somehow that there are other  tags in the HTML-code or I am doing something wrong in general...

Here is the HTML-code :

```
<div class="cbox"><article class="cf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<header>
<h1 itemprop="headline">Anzündhilfen: So bringen Sie die Kohle zur Weissglut</h1>
<em class="date">
<span class="my-color" itemprop="publisher">MyMagzine</span> 09/2018 vom <time datetime="2018-05-08" itemprop="datePublished">8. Mai 2018</time> | aktualisiert am <time datetime="2018-05-11" itemprop="dateModified">11. Mai 2018</time> </em>
<p>
von <span itemprop='author'>My Author</span> </p>
</header>
<p class="lead">Eine perfekte Glut ohne Rauch und Gestank bringen nur sogenannte Anzündkamine ­zustande. Aber zwei solche Produkte sind ­unsicher. </p>
<figure class="image-box cf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<img src="/image/?m=Artikel&rid=1113094&attr=bild&thumb=thumb_yRsBeq_resize_300_200.png" alt="Funken sprühen  (Bild: CHRISTIAN BIRMELE)" itemprop="contentUrl">
<figcaption>
<p itemprop="description">Funken sprühen (Bild: CHRISTIAN BIRMELE)</p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
Here is my text that I would like to get out of this. Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla.&nbsp;
<br /> <br />My Magazine has this title inbetween&nbsp;
<br /> <br />Here is more text I also want to get our of this. [...]</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required text

```
//article/figure/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Thank you - this almost works :) The problem now: It does not deliver what is after the `<br>` tags - which is also needed in my case. Do I need to make a second `xpath` to get those or is there way to all do it in one step (i.e. getting out everything that is before `</article>`?

Comment: Actually this should return the list of text nodes, so make sure that you use code that allows you to return the list of nodes instead of single node

Comment: I do : `inputNodes = bodyNode?.xpath(xpath); for node in inputNodes { if let myText = node.content { print(myText) } }` - is this wrong ? (again: with this I do not get everything needed...)

Comment: Found it ! See my solution added. Thank you very much for this great help!!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4549554/andersson), I found a solution !

The trick is to use `node.text` - since the xpath (Andersson's sulution) provides, now returns text !

Here it is:

```
xpath = "//article/figure/following-sibling::text()"

if let inputNodes = bodyNode?.xpath(xpath) {
    for node in inputNodes {
        print(node.text)
    }
}
```